# How to construct bash command and arguments for ssh / su -c

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm backing stuff up from an array list of sources, a bit like this simplified version:

```bsh
sources=( file1 file2 "other stuff" )
backupcommand="rsync -ar ${a[@]} dest/"
su backupuser -c "$backupcommand"
```

The problem is creating `$backupcommand` with the correct escaping. The above means rsync looks for one file called "other" and another called "stuff", rather than one file called "other stuff"

How can I construct a quoted command for `sh -c ...` (or `ssh ...` etc.). I'm using bash.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1):

First we need a way to show what we have in our bash array, `sources`. A good way seems to be using `printf '%s\n' <args>` which will output one line per argument in `<args>`.

For example:

```
$ sources=( file1 file2 "other stuff" )
$ printf '%s' "${sources[@]}"
file1
file2
other stuff
```

If we use this command as our `backupcommand` we can see what the backup program (e.g. `rsync`) would actually receive as its arguments. So lets say that the command we want to run via `bash -c ...` (or `ssh ...`) is `printf '%s\n' <args>` and that we have two arguments, `file1` and `other stuff`.

We want to run this command on the destination shell:

```
$ printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff
file1
other stuff
```

So to get that as one argument we'll need to quote it. We can use `""` or `''` or `\` for quoting. We can use `printf '%s\n'` again on this, to check that we have done this successfully...

```
$ # With backslashes:
$ printf '%s\n' printf\ \'%s\\n\'\ file1\ other\\\ stuff
printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff

$ # With single quotes
$ printf '%s\n' 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' file1 other\ stuff'
printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff

$ # Using a variable to store the command...
$ the_command='printf '\''%s\n'\'' file1 other\ stuff'
$ # ..then using that variable as a single argument...
$ printf '%s\n' "$the_command"
printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff
```

So all good so far. In the last version we quoted the variable containing the command.

Now can we use an array for the arguments? What we need to do is quote/escape each item of the array and append it to the single string `the_command`.

`${var[@]}` tells bash to produce one token per array item. But these aren't escaped because they've already been interpreted. So we can't just throw that into a shell command string. So we need a way to apply quoting.

Bash has `printf '%q' arg` to quote `arg`. We can use command substitution `$(...)`

```
$ sources=( file1 other\ stuff )
$ the_command=printf\ \'%s\\n\'
$ for item in "${sources[@]}"
  do the_command="$the_command "$(printf '%q' "$item")
  done
$ printf '%s\n' "$the_command"
printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff
```

Hooray! However, we can clean this up more like so:

```
$ sources=( file1 other\ stuff )
$ the_command="printf '%s\\n'"$(printf ' %q' "${sources[@]}")
$ printf '%s\n' "$the_command"
printf '%s\n' file1 other\ stuff

$ # And as final proof...
$ bash -c "$the_command"
file1
other stuff
```

### Applied to the original problem:

```
sources=( file1 file2 "other stuff" )
backupcommand="rsync -ar "$(printf ' %q' "${sources[@]}")" dest/"
su backupuser -c "$backupcommand"
```

### Summary

- `printf '%q' arg` quotes `arg`
- command substituion `$(...)` creates a single token from the output of the command.
- various quoting/escaping methods are available; pick the most readable one!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding escaped quotes around your array like this

```
backupcommand="rsync -ar \"${a[@]}\" dest/"
```

Comment: Hi, sorry you got downvoted (not by me) - not a nice way to welcome a new contributor! Thanks for your answer. This doesn't work, however, because it converts the array to a single quoted string/token.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote. I just made a few tests and what can I say... 
You are absolutely right, guess I deserve the downvote ;)